# Restricted Tenant acces to an external user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have access to multiple tenants in Azure with different user names. For one of my tenant - suppose `xyz.onmicrosoft.com` - an external user `test@dev.contoso.com` got access saying restricted tenant.

This user have never been granted any access to `xyz.onmicrosoft.com`. It surprises me how this user even gets into this tenant.

Can anyone explain?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error when logged in with external user:***

[image]

**To resolve the issue,** try clearing the cookies/browser data or open a new browser session where the previous sign-in history to Azure Portal is not present.

If still the issue persists, Try using **Incognito window** and sign-in.

After trying the above, try signing-in to Azure Portal and the external user with no access will not be able to sign-in.

In order to **restrict access to external or guest user**, you can select below option:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Users -> User settings*

[image]